# Bad output for SwatchLegend using LegendMarker with an EdgeForm

Tags: graphics, legending

Consider the following input which should give a legend with a red rectangle and a black frame:

```
SwatchLegend[{Red}, {"A"}, LegendMarkers -> {Graphics[{EdgeForm[
  Directive[Black, Thickness[0.3]]], Rectangle[]}]},  LegendMarkerSize -> 80]
```

Using Mathematica 10.0.2 on linux I get:

[image]

Clearly, this is not the desired edge for the rectangle. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Note: A simple workaround in this case is to draw a "frame" by adding a second rectangle behind the one I want that can act as a frame.

Comment: I don't see a question here. What are asking us to do for you?

Comment: Nothing, I just want to know whether this is a bug or not.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. I think the edge is drawn somewhat transparent; i.e., with an opacity less than  1.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you were expecting?

```
SwatchLegend[{Red}, {"A"}, 
  LegendMarkers -> 
    {Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Black, Thickness[0.3], Opacity[1]]], Rectangle[]}]}, 
  LegendMarkerSize -> 80]
```

[image: swatch]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I wonder why SwatchLegend changes the opacity of the edge...

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the effect of default marker style for legend markers:

```
Legending`LegendDump`$DefaultMarkerStyle
```

> `EdgeForm[Directive[Opacity[0.3], GrayLevel[0]]]`

If you like, you can reset the default edge opacity to `Opacity[1]`:

```
Legending`LegendDump`$DefaultMarkerStyle = EdgeForm[Opacity[1]];

SwatchLegend[{Red}, {"A"}, LegendMarkers -> {Graphics[{EdgeForm[
  Directive[Black, Thickness[0.3]]], Rectangle[]}]},  LegendMarkerSize -> 80]
```

[image]